# How android LED enabled during use of the app?

Tags: java, android

Requirement：

The LED lights up and displays a color during the use of the app.

Can the Notification LED be displayed only in the off state?

Is there a way to enable LEDs when using the app?

Or does Android have other APIs to control LED lights?

My app is registered in manifest.

```
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
```

Comment: Some [useful info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746303/controling-androids-front-led-light).

Comment: Can the Notification API enable the LED when the screen is turned on? I tried it. But failed.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, without Root the LED cannot be directly managed.

Using Root it should be possibile via "/dev/input/event..." interrogation.

Comment: My app is registered in manifest.

    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"

    Can the Notification API enable the LED when the screen is turned on?

Comment: When the screen is turned on it's NOT possibile to change LED status/color using normal Android API. Maybe via Reflection but I never tried and neither know what variable/class to use using reflection. The only available way is access hardware directly from "/dev/input/event..." but it requires Root.